# Aligning left and right in a simple footer

Tags: html, alignment

I'm currently working on a simple footer, and I would like to align one line of text left and the other to the right.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div id="footer">
   Last Updated: October 15, 2012 <!--left align-->
   Contact Us  Login <!--right align (these will be links)-->
</div>

#footer {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: .9em;
color: #24ACAE;
border-top: 1px solid #24ACAE;
margin-left: 90px;
margin-right: 90px;
padding-top: 5px;
}
```

The above code results in the two lines of text being next to each other and I've tried various ways of fixing this such as putting the the 2nd line in a span and aligning right and even putting the lines into a table. None of what I have tried has resulted in both lines being properly aligned.

Using a `margin-left` alone does not work because when the first line is updated and becomes longer, it will push the second line downwards. Relative positioning seems to have the same issue.

Hopefully there's something simple that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="footer">
<span style="float:left;">Last Updated: October 15, 2012</span>
<span style="float:right;">Contact Us  Login</span>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

putting them in spans, and styling the spans should accomplish what you want!

**UPDATE**
you could also do this with css, if you didn't want it inline, with your html code. like so:

```
<style>
.left {float:left;}
.right {float:right;}
</style>
```

and then

```
<div id="footer">
<div id="footer">
<span class="left">Last Updated: October 15, 2012</span>
<span class="right">Contact Us  Login</span>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

this will also allow you to reuse these css classes throughout the page, allowing you to apply the float:left/right; properties to any DOM element

**Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvAkU/)** showing it working (if it isn't looking right, resize your browser, as it didn't have enough space to fit all the text in one line, in my browser window initially)

Comment: Ah of course. I never got used to using float. I generally use margins for positioning elements. Thanks.